# Casting void* to long*

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am implementing a multi-threaded program in which I am waiting for `myThread` to reurn a value. I am doing it as follows:

```
result = pthread_join(myThread, &retValue);
```

where `myThread` returns a `(void *)returnValue`. My program gives a `Segmentation Fault` when I try to print the return value using:

```
printf("Returned Value: %lu", *(long *)retValue;
```

Can anyone tell why this is happening and how do I fix this ?

Comment: Without seeing the code of the thread function, we can only guess. My guess is you're returning a pointer to a local variable, which goes out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: According to the doc, the `value_ptr` parameter of `pthread_join` is filled with the value passed to `pthread_exit`. This means that if you don't call `pthread_exit` and just let the entry point function of the thread return, you don't get a value. Are you using `pthread_exit`?

Comment: No. I am just using `return (void*)returnValue`. Is that creating the problem?

Comment: I got it wrong, letting the thread finish and return a `void*` is the same as calling `pthread_exit`. Well, make sure the pointer you return will be valid once your thread has terminated (e.g. not thread-local storage and not stack memory).

Comment: @Barmar and @zneak - I would have said that was the problem if `returnValue` wasn't global. But it is.

Comment: You'll have to show your code. Debugging is hard enough when you have the code in front of you, it's practically impossible without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've confused the return type.

At the end of your thread you cast from a `(long)` to a `(void *)`.

```
return (void *) count ;
```

Back in main, you are casting `(void *)` to a `(long *)` and then trying to dereference it.  Since count is probably a small number, treating that as a memory address goes boom.  Treat it as a `(long)` instead:

```
printf("Returned value: %lu", (long) retValue) ;
```